# How does a numpy function handle a logical if operator for the axis argument?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I stumbled onto this on accident, but can't make sense of what is going on.  I am doing a K-means clustering assignment with images and trying to vectorize the code to make it run as fast as possible.  I came up with the following code:

```
image_values =np.array( [[[ 0.36302522  0.51708686  0.20952381]
                      [ 0.46330538  0.69915968  0.2140056 ]
                      [ 0.7904762   0.93837535  0.27002802]
                      [ 0.78375351  0.89187676  0.24201682]
                      [ 0.57871151  0.79775912  0.24593839]
                      [ 0.2896359   0.39103645  0.64481789]
                      [ 0.23809525  0.30924368  0.64257705]]

                     [[ 0.36302522  0.51708686  0.20952381]
                      [ 0.46330538  0.69915968  0.2140056 ]
                      [ 0.7904762   0.93837535  0.27002802]
                      [ 0.78375351  0.89187676  0.24201682]
                      [ 0.57871151  0.79775912  0.24593839]
                      [ 0.2896359   0.39103645  0.64481789]
                      [ 0.23809525  0.30924368  0.64257705]]

                     [[ 0.36302522  0.51708686  0.20952381]
                      [ 0.46330538  0.69915968  0.2140056 ]
                      [ 0.7904762   0.93837535  0.27002802]
                      [ 0.78375351  0.89187676  0.24201682]
                      [ 0.57871151  0.79775912  0.24593839]
                      [ 0.2896359   0.39103645  0.64481789]
                      [ 0.23809525  0.30924368  0.64257705]]])
means = np.array([[0.909,0.839,0.6509],[0.813,0.808,0.694],[0.331,0.407,0.597]]) #random centroids
err = 1
while err > .01:
    J = [np.sum((image_values-avg)**2, axis = 2) for avg in means]
    K = np.argmin(J, axis = 0)
    old_means = means
    means = np.array([np.mean(image_values[K==i], axis ==True) for i in range(len(means))])
    print means
    err = abs(sum(old_means)-sum(means))
    print err
```

In each new means calculation, I used my K array to select which pixel values should be included in each mean calculation but I couldn't get the axis to agree.  I actually made a typo where instead of axis=3, I typed axis==3 and it worked!  I tried a bunch of different numbers, and found out that it doesn't matter what the number is, the result is the same.  I tried a bunch of numbers and Booleans with the equal operator they didn't work.  I've gone through the documentation, but I couldn't figure it out.

What does numpy do when it gets a logical if in the axis argument of one of its array functions?

Thanks!

Comment: In Python, ```True``` evaluates to one and ```False``` evaluates to zero in a numeric expression. ```int(True) -> 1```

Comment: That's true - the question is not about what I put in the axis argument.  I found I could put anything in there (even a char) and it still works.  The question is about what the logical if operator does in the axis argument. am I using the right words in the question (argument, logical if, etc)?

Comment: Which version of numpy are you using?  (Check `numpy.__version__`.)

Comment: With numpy 1.12.1, I get `TypeError: an integer is required` if I try `axis=True`.

Comment: Could it be that you have ```axis``` defined somewhere in your namespace? Check
```y = 5; 
f = lambda x, y: (x, y); 
f(1, y==True)```. Here you check if ```y``` is ```True```, which it isn't, it is ```5```, and then the result of this evaluation is passed as second argument to the function.

Comment: @Warren: I am using numpy version 1.11.1.  To duplicate my implementation try axis==True, not axis=True

Comment: @Niklas: I do have %pylab which brings in all of matplotlab.pyplot which has an axis parameter.  I'll try to run it without the pylab magic.

Comment: Unless the name `axis` is defined, using `axis==True` will result in a `NameError`.  If `axis` *is* defined, then `axis == True` is an expression that will probably evaluate to `False` (unless `axis` happens to equal True).  The result is the same: you are passing a boolean value for the `axis` argument, and in numpy 1.12.1, that results in a `TypeError`.

Comment: In older numpy, when given as the `axis` argument, `False` acts like 0 and `True` acts like 1.

Comment: I pulled out the pylab magic and the function threw a "NameError: name 'axis' is not defined".  So the matplotlib axis parameter was being evaluated.  Something is still unclear because simply replacing axis==True with False in the function call now throws an error whereas it didn't before.  Using axis=0 produces the wrong dimensions for the algorithm (as I wrote it) to evaluate correctly.  Back to the drawing board.  Thanks for your help in understanding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure I fully understood what you're trying to do. Here's what I assume; You have one single image with RGB values and you would like to cluster the pixels within this image. Each centroid will thus define one value for each color channel respectively. I assume that each row in your `means` matrix is one centroid with the columns being the RGB values.

In your approach, I think you might have a mistake in the way you are subtracting the centroids. You will need to create a distance matrix for each centroid (at the moment your not subtracting each color channel correctly).

Here's one proposition. Please note that with given example data you will run into a `NaN` error since not all centroids have pixels that are closest to them. You also might need to adjust the stopping criterion to your needs.

```
err = 1
while err > 0.1:
    # There are three centroids. We would like to compute the
    # distance for each pixel to each centroid. Here, the image
    # is thus replicated three times.
    dist = np.tile(image_values, (3,1,1,1))

    # The 2D matrix needs to be reshaped to fit the dimensions of
    # the dist matrix. With the new shape, the matrix can directly
    # be subtracted.
    means2 = means.reshape(3,3,1,1)

    # Subtract each respective RGB value of the centroid for 
    # each "replica" of the image
    J = np.power(dist - means2, 2)

    # Sum the r,g,b channels together to get the total distance for a pixel
    J = J.sum(axis=1)

    # Check for which cluster the pixel is closest
    K = np.argmin(J, axis=0)

    # I couldn't think of a better way than this loop
    newMeans = np.zeros((3,3))
    for i in range(means.shape[0]): # do each centroid
        # In axis 1 there are pixels which we would like to
        # average for each color channel (axis 0 are the RGB channels)
        newMeans[i,:] = image_values[:,K==i].mean(axis=1)

    err = np.power(means - newMeans, 2).sum()
    means = newMeans
```